# Why ip addresses on local network

Tags: networking, dhcp, tcp-ip

My question is more "philosophical" than practical.
Since all hosts on a Ethernet local network NIC have a MAC address that identifies them uniquely, why does the dhcp service assigns them an ip address? The router even uses the ARP protocol to match the local ip with the MAC address. So it seems to me that the local ip is not necessary to identify the target host of an incoming packet.

Comment: MAC address are not unique

Comment: It's the same reason why one lightswitch does not control only one lamp in your house.  Read about the basics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_stack)

Answer (score 3):

`MAC` addresses are link local, and are part of the medium access control [(MAC) sublayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_access_control) which together with the  logical link control (LLC) data communication protocol layer make up the [Data Link layer.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer.) IP addresses are routable, addressable via DNS, are usually associated with the [Network layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer), 1 level up. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

Additional resources:

https://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Computer_Science/understanding_layers.asp

Comment: I specified on the local network only.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that if you only look at a local network, IP addresses seem redundant. There are several reasons though why you would want them:

- You can configure more than one IP address per network interface, e. g. for running different services on them. In fact, with version 6 of IP, this usually happens already in the most basic configuration even on simple devices.
- Perhaps you want to reach somebody in another network. How would you do that? For this you need something that spans several networks. An Internet. That's what IP is designed for. With IP you can route packets between networks. That is not possible with a protocol like ARP.
- MAC addresses, at least by its original idea (it has changed a bit since), are not meant to be changed, and assigned by the company you bought the hardware from. IP addresses you can assign and organize at will, as long as you stick to the IP addresses that are free for private use.
- MAC addresses have only 48 bits. That may seem like a big number, but you certainly do not want to rely on this as the only way to uniquely identify devices all over the world.

Comment: That was exactly my point: On the local network. I understand why ip addresses are essential when linking through the WAN.

Comment: @frepie I can't imagine [subnetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) a local network without IP addresses.

Comment: ok, I also addressed wan, which is now clear was not your question. But my first point addresses assigning many IPs to one MAC and third point addresses lan, like what @ElderGeek means with subnetting.